# Compare multiple records in pandas

Tags: pandas, string-comparison

Trying to compare df1 and df2 for 'Cntr No' AND either the value in any of the column of df2 ['Labour Cost', Material Cost', 'Amount in Estimate Currency'] must be matched with df1's Total.

For example df1 OOLU 3868088 is matched with df2 OOLU 3868088 AND the Total value of df1 "28" is matched with df2's "Labour Cost" value of '28'.

df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Cntr No': ['OOLU 3868088','OOLU 3868088','OOLU 3868088','TRIU 0625840','TRIU 0625840','TRIU 0625840','TRIU 1234567','OOLU 6232016','OOLU 0981231','OOLU 1212444'], 
               'Total': [12,28,48,119,82.5,11.0,18.0,11.0,13.0,10.0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cntr No': ['OOLU 3868088','OOLU 3868088','OOLU 3868088','TRIU 0625840','TRIU 0625840','TRIU 0625840','TRIU 1234567'],  
                  'Labour Cost': [0.0,0.0,28.0,0.0,54.0,0.0,0.0], 
                  'Material Cost':[0.00,12.0,58.91,82.5,54.0,0.0,16.0],
                  'Amount in Estimate Currency':[48.00,12.00,87.81,82.5,119.0,12.0,16.0]})
```

Expected output:

```
    Cntr No        Total    Tally_with_df2
0   OOLU 3868088    12.0    Yes
1   OOLU 3868088    28.0    Yes
2   OOLU 3868088    48.0    Yes
3   TRIU 0625840    119.0   Yes
4   TRIU 0625840    82.5    Yes
5   TRIU 0625840    11.0    No
6   TRIU 1234567    18.0    No
```

Used code: this is the below code I tried on but doesn't able to achieve my requirements

```
cols = ['Labour Cost', 'Material Cost', 'Amount in Estimate Currency']

 d = {k: set(v.values()) for k, v in \
    df_co.set_index('Cntr No')[cols].to_dict(orient='index').items()}

df['Tally'] = [j in d.get(i, set()) for i, j in zip(df['Cntr No'], df['Total'])]
df['Tally'] = df['Tally'].map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

df1:

```
Cntr No                       object
Serviced By                   object
Location                      object
WO No                         object
WASH - CHEMICAL              float64
PTI - CHILL                  float64
WASHING CONTAINER AGENT      float64
WASH - CHEMICAL AGENT        float64
WASHING CONTAINER -AGENT     float64
BUNDLING/UNBUNDLING OF FR    float64
PTI - AUTO                   float64
PTI                          float64
Struct Repair - Labour       float64
Struct Repair - Material     float64
Machy Repair - Labour        float64
Total                        float64
Vendor                        object
Sz                            object
Ty                            object
CO                            object
WO Date                       object
WO ID                         object
```

df2:

```
 Cntr No                            object
Equipment Size/type Group Code     object
Labour Cost                       float64
Material Cost                     float64
Amount in Estimate Currency       float64
Remarks                            object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, we can create a `groupby` data from df2 for every unique Cntr No.

```
## this is grouped data
to_remove = df2.select_dtypes(['object']).columns.values.tolist()

df3 = (df2
.groupby('Cntr No')
.apply(lambda df: set(np.concatenate(df.loc[:, df.columns.difference(to_remove)].values))))

## df3 looks like this - using set for faster speed
print(df3)

Cntr No
OOLU 3868088    {0.0, 12.0, 48.0, 87.81, 58.91, 28.0}
TRIU 0625840           {0.0, 12.0, 82.5, 54.0, 119.0}
TRIU 1234567                              {16.0, 0.0}


## this function ensures all cases are handles
def get_value(x, data):
    if x['Cntr No'] not in data.index:
        return 'Not Found'
    else:
        if x['Total'] in data[x['Cntr No']]:
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'

## next we do a simple look-up
df1['Tally_with_df2'] = df1.apply(lambda x: get_value(x, df3), axis=1)

print(df1)

        Cntr No  Total Tally_with_df2
0  OOLU 3868088   12.0            Yes
1  OOLU 3868088   28.0            Yes
2  OOLU 3868088   48.0            Yes
3  TRIU 0625840  119.0            Yes
4  TRIU 0625840   82.5            Yes
5  TRIU 0625840   11.0             No
6  TRIU 1234567   18.0             No
```

Comment: thank, but there is an error on look-up code: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. KeyError: ('OOLU 6232016', 'occurred at index 1')

Comment: @leong I cannot see the error at my side. Could you check the dtypes of values or 'OOLU 6232016' value is present in both the data frames.

Comment: df3 sample : TRIU 0783320               {GP, 70.0, 40FL, 48.0, 118.0} Maybe my df2 have another 2 string columns ?

Comment: @leong make sure you add all string columns here in the list `df.columns.difference(['Cntr No', 'add_string_column'])]` because in the end, we want a set of all numeric values

Comment: i have added the actual df1 and df2 columns in my post. Do i have to add in all ?? pls see my previous post update

Comment: @leong I've updated the answer. We need to remove all non-numeric columns for this to work. Please check and let me know.

Comment: df3 : TRIU 0783320               {48.0, 70.0, 118.0}  object been removed but still same error. i checked df1 have the Cntr No = OOLU 6232016 But df2 does not has this Cntr No record. That's why the error?

Comment: yes, that could be a reason. What do you want to do with those cases when Cntr No is not found? Add few rows (2 or 3) in data in your question, I'll modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: i have added 3 row of data in df1. If the Cntr no not found in df2 to indicate "Not Found" under the "Tally_with_df2"

Comment: BINGO! Thank! :)